# Display AlertDialog in android after specified time

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm in a situation where, `AlertDialog` should pop up after specific time.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PDFDisplayActivity.this);
          alertDialog.setTitle(" Auto Logout");
          alertDialog.setMessage("You will be logged out automatically after 1 minute.");

          alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                 waitTimer = new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    public void onFinish() {
                        Intent logout = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                        logout.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(logout);
                        finish();
                    }
                 }.start();
              }
          });

          alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please logout when you are done reading the agreement.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              }
          });
          alertDialog.show();
```

In the code above, when `Yes` is clicked, customer would be logged of automatically after one minute. When `No` is clicked, no action would be taken, but after some time, the alert should pop again, i.e, whenever customer clicks `No`, `AlertDialog` should appear after specified time. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Yes. You can schedule a timer to run after a specific amount of time. Have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: @user2045570 Thanks for the reply!! Let me implement that solution!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
public Handler Alerthandler = new Handler()
        {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg)
                {

                    switch (msg.what)
                        {

                        case 0:
                          //put your alertDialog code here
                            break;
                        }

                };
        };
```

And to show your AlertDialog send a message to above handler as,

```
Alerthandler.sendEmptyMessageAtTime(0,1000/*your time in millis*/);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use Timer class too to achieve this. When the timer fires you can show the dialog. Here is the reference [schedule (TimerTask task, long delay)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long%29)

Answer (score 0):

This worked!!

```
public void alert(){
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PDFDisplayActivity.this);
  alertDialog.setTitle(" Auto Logout");
alertDialog.setMessage("You will be logged out automatically after 1 minute.");

alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

     waitTimer = new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                Intent logout = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                logout.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(logout);
                finish();
            }
         }.start();
    }
});

alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please logout when you are done reading the agreement.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     waitTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                alert();
            }
         }.start();

    }
});
alertDialog.show();
```

}